# Binary classification. Naming of metric TP+FP/FullSet

Tags: binary-data, metric

I have not been able to find the naming of this metric;
TP+FP / FullSet (TP+FP + TN+FN) [for Binary/Binomial Classification]

Basically percentage of how many Predicted Positives can I find within my dataset. (How often does the prediction system tell me to bet money before rolling the dice?).
If this previously has been asked and there exists a holy grail of metric explanations, please give me a pointer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean prevalence? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not a metric**

Basically, you want to know how much of the test data was labeled as positive ones. And that depends **only** on where you set your cut in the prediction probabilities. You will have the same score for a perfect classifier (100% TP and 0% FP) as well as for a complete garbage classifier (0% TP and 100% FP), if the threshold remains the same.

This is not a metric but counts the percentage of the positive labels above a certain prediction threshold.